How do I prevent an extended frame when suspending and resuming an ffmpeg process in C#?
I have a c# application where I have control of an ffmpeg (https://www.ffmpeg.org/) process. I am using it to capture video and audio, either from desktop or webcam. I am using code similar to the answer from this question (How to pause/resume ffmpeg video capture in windows from C# application) to suspend and resume the process. However, while suspended, the captured video extends the frame it was suspended on for the entire duration of the suspension.
My arguments passed into the process:
-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=\"Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)\" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt rgb24 output.mp4
I have tried adding -vf setpts=N/FR/TB to my arguments, and this works partially. It successfully prevents the extended frame, but then seriously affects the playback speed of the video.
How do I prevent this extended frame from occurring, or prevent the additional argument from affecting the playback speed of the video? I am hoping for a solution in C#, although if there is an issue with my command line arguments that is an easier fix, that is great also.
My ideal outcome is to have the process record, be suspended then resumed, and have the video play normally without having captured anything while suspended.
Record for 10 seconds, suspend for 20 seconds, record for 30 seconds, end recording -> should result in a 40 second video.
I'm aware that this question may be better suited for the super user stack exchange, but as I am primarily looking for a c# solution, I am asking here first.
